# PayPal's recent TLS 1.2 / HTTP 1.1 updates and when to use it

Tags: php, ssl, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

With regards to Paypal's recent [security update](https://www.paypal-notice.com/en/TLS-1.2-and-HTTP1.1-Upgrade/) I have started adding two additional options to my cURL code, those being:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
```

I set `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION` since not setting it seems to default to "*lets CURL decide which version to use*" - whilst I don't want or like to hardcode the setting for future compatibility reasons, can cURL be trusted to always set `HTTP 1.1` if support is available?

Secondly, I set `CURLOPT_SSLVERSION` to `6`, which is `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2` because I have read that..

> Some environments may be capable of TLS 1.2 but it is not in their list of defaults, so need the SSL version option to be set.

Now, an additional query is I notice at that PayPal link it only makes mention of endpoints, but how about when you're making `cURL` requests to their other URL's like the common: `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr` used for things such as IPN listeners? Does that still require TLS 1.2 and HTTP 1.1?

Comment: (a) What happened when you tried it? (b) Why not just use it anyway and have the same configuration for everything?

Comment: @EJP Well it seems to work, but it would be good to get a rundown on the best way to handle all this for future compatibility and if the way I am doing it is the recommended method as well as my other questions.

Comment: We've been defaulting to HTTP/1.1 for ages now and I have never needed to use the `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1` option. Any reason you need to set it?

Comment: @apokryfos I guess just the description of not setting it being "*default, lets CURL decide which version to use*" was a little vague; I would have felt more comfortable if it said that it would always choose the latest version supported when possible.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using their SDK to interact with their server?

Comment: @Bryan Not 100% sure, it's old code that I was looking at again because of the PayPal updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

www.paypal.com is using HTTP/2 as seen in

```
curl --silent --head https://www.paypal.com | head -n 1
HTTP/2 302
```

According to [official docs](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION.html), your best option is

> CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0
>
> Attempt HTTP 2 requests. libcurl will fall back to HTTP 1.1 if HTTP 2 can't be negotiated with the server.

cURL will fallback to the required HTTP/1.1 if HTTP/2 can not be used.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
```

This option could be even better

> CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS
>
> Attempt HTTP 2 over TLS (HTTPS) only. libcurl will fall back to HTTP 1.1 if HTTP 2 can't be negotiated with the HTTPS server. For clear text HTTP servers, libcurl will use 1.1. (Added in 7.47.0)

For [php cURL extension docs](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php)

> CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2 (integer)
>       Available since PHP 7.0.7 and cURL 7.43.0 
>   CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS (integer)
>       Available since PHP 7.0.7 and cURL 7.47.0

If your PHP version does not define those constants you can try something like

```
defined('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0') || define('CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0', 65536);
```

For CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS the value seems to be.

```
CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS = 4
```

Using the integer value instead of the PHP constant could work as long as the `libcurl` backing package version supports it.

On `rpm` based Linux you can check with

```
rpm -q libcurl4
libcurl4-7.60.0-lp150.2.6.1.x86_64
```

Comparing with PHP (command line)

```
php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -i 'curl info'
cURL Information => 7.60.0
```

also with

```
php -r 'print_r(curl_version());' | grep 'version'
[version_number] => 474112
[ssl_version_number] => 0
[version] => 7.60.0
[ssl_version] => OpenSSL/1.1.0h
[libz_version] => 1.2.11
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Sorry, forgot to say I am using PHP (just added the tag); looking at the PHP docs they don't currently make mention of the `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0` or `CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2TLS` flags unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Btw, I think you got this bit back to front `defined('CURL_VERSION_HTTP2') || define('CURL_VERSION_HTTP2', 65536);` - `HTTP` goes *before* `VERSION`.

Comment: Correct, it's fixed now. It would work anyway as long as you use the same constant but must be consistent with docs.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best and easiest way for further compatibility is just to try to keep your libraries up to date, mainly `curl`, and `openssl` (check [nghttp](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http2.html)), this may help to prevent adding some constants and by using the defined "defaults" things should be working fine.

From the docs: https://ec.haxx.se/http-versions.html

> Since perhaps mid 2016, curl will default to use HTTP/1.1 for HTTP servers. If you connect to HTTPS and you have a libcurl that has HTTP/2 abilities built-in, curl will attempt to use HTTP/2 automatically or fall down to 1.1 in case the negotiation failed. Non-HTTP/2 capable curls get 1.1 over HTTPS by default.